# Что делает оператор CS: в команде MOV в ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер

```
MOV AX, CS:DX
MOV AX, DX
```

Во втором случае из DX копируется значение и помещается в AX. Что делает оператор CS: в первой команде?

Comment: ЕМНИП первая команда помещает в AX слово, располагающееся в памяти по адресу, равному значению регистра DX, в сегменте, на который указывает CS.

Comment: `CS:` - это не оператор. Оператор в данном случае `MOV`, а `CS:DS` - это второй операнд

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В команде MOV AX, CS:DX второй операнд, представляющий собой адрес ячейки памяти, содержит префикс замены сегмента (CS:). При сегментной адресации памяти в архитектуре x86 адрес любой ячейки формируется из двух компонентов: сегментного адреса и смещения. Сегментные адреса хранятся в сегментных регистрах: DS, ES, CS и SS. Команды процессора, обращающиеся к памяти, могут в качестве первого байта своего кода содержать префикс замены сегмента, с помощью которого процессор определяет, из какого сегментного регистра взять сегментный адрес.

Например, для сегментного регистра CS код префикса равен 2Eh. Если префикс отсутствует, сегментный адрес берется из регистра DS (хотя для него тоже предусмотрен свой префикс). По умолчанию, все данные адресуются через сегментный регистр DS. В случае замены сегментного регистра его следует указывать явно.

Таким образом, первая команда пересылает содержимое ячейки памяти, адресуемой вторым операндом, в регистр AX. Регистр DX в данном случае содержит смещение.

Answer (score 1):

Первая команда - копирование значения *ячейки памяти* по адресу `CS:DX` в регистр `AX`. `CS` - это не оператор, а сегментный регистр. Фактический адрес в данном случае рассчитывается как `CS * 16 + DX` (или `CS << 4 + DX`).

Вторая команда - копирование значения из *регистра* `DX` в регистр `AX`. Память при этом не участвует.

Comment: Размер сегмента 64k, откуда у вас там 16?

Comment: @gbg, физический адрес состоит из 20 бит. *16 - это сдвиг значения сегментного регистра на 4 бита влево. См. тут например: https://studfiles.net/preview/2652887/page:8/

Comment: `CS * 16 + DX` работает только в реальном режиме. В защищенном всё сложнее.

Comment: @insolor - спасибо.